# Alternative to write in Console

Tags: java, user-interface, serial-port, action, serial-communication

I have a Serial communication between my pc and an Arduino.

I have implemented the Serial Communication thanks to this example:
http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Two_way_communcation_with_the_serial_port

I´m able to send (From Console) and receive data from Arduino without problems.

Now I created a GUI which is displaying the Arduino´s data. Everything is working until here.

```
-----------------------------
EXAMPLE : 
I send from console: ">?L"
I receive ">L|50|" 
------------------------------
```

In the example 50 is a value of a sensor mounted on arduino.

The problem is:

I want to add some buttons to my GUI and I want that the button act exactly in same way of the action of writing on the console. 
So, I click a button and it sends ">?L" to my Arduino. I´m not able to do that, is there someone who can help me?
Of course I know the structure that there is under a button:

```
JButton btnLength = new JButton("Length");
        btnLength.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
}
```

My question is: What do I have to write in the actionPerformed function?

Thanks,
Fab.